# How to disable creation of myisam table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, myisam

myisam engine is used by mysql system tables, so it can not be disabled simply. Is there any way to only disable creation of new myisam tables while keeping myisam exists in system?

Comment: you can specify engine while creating new tables.

Comment: I'm not the end user. I just want to prevent others to create myisam tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [default_storage_engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_default-storage-engine) server variable to `innodb`, for example, in your option file, which is the default in newer versions of MySQL.

Comment: I'm not the end user. I just want to prevent others to create myisam tables.

Comment: Yeah, this wouldn't disable the MyISAM storage engine, which I don't think would be possible.

Comment: I know that disable MyISAM storage engine is imposible. I just want to  disable CREATE NEW MyISAM tables.

Answer (score 1):

I've writen a plugin to do this. It can disable creating new MYISAM tables.

https://github.com/xiezhenye/mysql-plugin-disable-myisam

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 5.7.8 and higher, [`disabled_storage_engines`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_disabled_storage_engines) is the parameter you're looking for. Add

```
disabled_storage_engines = "MyISAM"
```

to your config file.